Equivalence between definitions of orthogonal groups of minus type: $GO_{2n}^{-}(q)$
I am working with the general orthogonal group of minus type over a finite field $F_q$ with $q=p^f$ elements.
In general, finite classical groups may be studied from different perspectives: as the fixed point subgroups under a Steinberg endomorphism of a semisimple algebraic group, or as groups fixing a certain classical form.
In this particular case I am considering two definitions.
The first is taken from the book of Malle and Testermann "Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type".
They define the general orthogonal group $GO_{2n}$ over an algebraically closed field $k = \overline{F}_p$ as the group of isometries
$$GO_{2n}=\{A \in GL_{2n} \mid f(Ax)=f(x) \text{ for all }x \in k^{2n} \},$$
where $f:k^{2n} \rightarrow k$ is the non-degenerate quadratic form: $f(x_1,...,x_{2n})=x_1x_{2n}+x_2x_{2n-1}+...+x_{n}x_{n+1}.$
Then, they consider the following element
$$
  g :=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
    I_{n-1}   & & & \\
       & 0 &1 &  \\
       & 1 &0 & \\
       &&&  I_{n-1} 
  \end{array} \right) \in  GO_{2n},
     $$
Moreover, let $F: GO_{2n} \rightarrow GO_{2n}$, $(a_{ij}) \mapsto (a_{ij}^q)^{-tr} $, i.e. the composition of the map sending a matrix to the inverse of its transpose with the standard $q$-Frobenius endomorphism.
The general orthogonal group of minus type over the field $F_q$ is defined as the fixed point subgroup of $gF$:
$$GO_{2n}^{-}(q)=(GO_{2n})_{gF}.$$
I'd like to prove that this coincides with the isometry group of a non-denegerate orthogonal form with Witt defect -1, defined on $V=F_q^{2n}$.
In particular in this context I am working with the basis
$$\mathcal{B}^{-}=(e_1,f_1,...,e_m,f_m)$$
and the quadratic form $Q$ such that:
$$Q(e_i)=Q(f_i)=(e_i,u_m)=(f_i,u_m)=(e_i,v_m)=(f_i,v_m)=0$$
$$(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}, Q(u_m)=Q(v_m)=1, (u_m,v_m)=\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}$$
where $\zeta \in F_q^2 \setminus F_q$ satisfies $\zeta^{q+1}=1$.
I am pretty stuck in proving that the first  definition is equivalent to the second (I am not interested in this particular $Q$, I am also looking for the most suitable $Q$ for proving the equivalence, first of all reording the basis $\mathcal{B}^{-}$ should work better). Any hint is greatly appreciated.
